# C# - Request to data URI scheme

Tags: c#, asp.net, request, data-uri, data-uri-scheme

I am using the `Google Charts API` in my `.NET` application and I would like to programmatically save the chart rendered as an image by passing the chat URI in an `AJAX` request to the server.

The problem is that the URI of the chart is a `data` URI scheme so it looks like this: `data:image/png;base64,abcdef...`

I tried to request this URI with the `HttpClient`, `WebClient` and `WebRequest` classes but all of these launched an exception saying that the URI prefix is not recognized or not handled...

Does anyone knows wich library I can use to request this kind of URI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By exploring the data URI scheme by myself, I finally understood that I didn't need to send a request to retrieve the image, as the bytes were already in the URI.

I managed to decode the base 64 string to an 8 bit stream and create the image :)

Below is a short example of my working code :)

```
// The data URI to the image
String imageLink = "data:image/png;base64,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"

// Split the string to escape the real data
var b64 = imageLink.Split(",".ToCharArray(), 2);

// Convert the base 64 String to byte array
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String(b64[1]);

// Open a stream from the byte array
MemoryStream imgStream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

// Generate the image from the stream
Image img = Image.FromStream(imgStream);

// Save the image
img.save("C:\\Images\\image.png");
```